# Django button to run script (to populate a database)

Tags: python, django, google-analytics

I have a pre-built python script that collects Google Analytics data, I am using this script to populate a database.

I have been given the instruction to write a web app where all of this data can be displayed in the form of a dashboard..

I want the user of the web app to be able to click on a button and then all the latest Google Analytics data will be pulled and added to the database in the backend and then the dashboard will display updated values.. But it seems like I can only add data to the db via the python shell? I have a script that can do that.. But I am confused as to where in django should I have this script and how to implement it

Should I put it in views, models or a separate file

PS: I would post the script but it is 400 lines of code to get that data

EDIT

```
def updateDB(request,x, y, z):
    return Database.objects.create(value1=x, value2 = y, value3 = z)
```

Comment: How long does the script take? The usual place would be to call the scrip from a view

Comment: So the script can take up to 20 minutes to go through all possible users.. So in views, I would want to write something like (Edited in question)

Comment: If it takes 20 minutes you should not run the script in the view. You should look into running the script asynchronously, celery might be one option

Comment: I would put the script in a separate file, then from the view you will import and call that function in the script.

Comment: Okay cool this is good guidance. What is celery? SO: I have my script and leave it as is, then call it into views and then what do I do with regards to functions etc.. once it is imported, what then?

Comment: It would still be separate scripts.. I need to "join" them in views

Comment: How much time interval  you store your data in dB?